# PyCharm cannot find data in venv by option "Find in path" (⌘⇧F)

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, jetbrains-ide, hotkeys, python-venv

When I usually try to find some data in my project, I use option "Find in path" (`⌘⇧F` for MAC). But this option for some reason does not affect the `venv` folder. And if I know for sure that in `venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/my_frame/my_file` there is function or variable I need, I cannot find it by `⌘⇧F`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at this [documentation link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/finding-and-replacing-text-in-project.html?keymap=secondary_macos#find_in_project) you will see that under the search bar there are several options like *In project*, *Module*, *Directory* and *Scope*.

If you want to search something that is not in the project (like virtualenv), you should select *Scope*.

Comment: Glad to help you! if this answer is the correct one please mark it as "correct" thanks